# How to get return data from another file outside of a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get some data returned from a function printed on the screen(In a

tag). In other words, I trying to call a function and output the return value to the screen. If you don't get what I mean here is some code:

foo.js:

```js
import random from "./script/stuff/myfantasticfile.js";

export const myFantasticFunction = () =>{
return "Hello world!";
}
```

App.jsx:

```js
import react from "react";
import Stuff from "./stuff.jsx"
import {myFantasticFunction} from "./foo.js"

function App(){
const myVariable = myFantasticFunction();
return(
<div>
<Stuff/>
<p>{myVariable}</p>
</div>
)
```

At first glance, the code looks fine, but when you run it, the

tag will return 'undefined'. However, the function is returning 'Hello world'.

I have tried to search on google, stackoverflow and some other online coding websites ie: grepper.

If anyone has any idea please share it to me by posting an answer.

Any help will be greatly appreceated

Comment: Hi alvin so basically what u want is to get the variable hello world and display it on the app.jsx and display it on p tag?

Comment: log `myVariable` (`console.log(myVariable)`) before returning the JSX and check its value

Comment: its working fine, check this- https://codesandbox.io/s/long-shape-o0o0c

Comment: can you console.log('myVariable : ',myVariable) under define const myVariable and what is output?

Comment: I'm sure there's something fantastic going on here... Is your function defined? All this should work, but I'm guessing something is hidden by the simplification of your code.

Comment: Ok thanks! everyone

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your function is not loaded when it render the component, I suggest to try that:

```
<p>{myVariable ? myVariable : '' }</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the bug by adding state to the variable, in other words I am assigning the return value to the state.
Code:

```
function App(){
const [myVariableState,setMyVariableState] = React.useState();
setMyVariableState(myFantasicFunction());
return(
<div>
<Stuff/>
<p>{myVariableState}</p>
</div>
)
}
```

Documentation links on how I solved it: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html